# How do I create a GCP SQL database sequentially in Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

For , I need to be able to provision multiple SQL DBs in GCP. These DBs also need to be on a VPC with a private IP address.

Config

```
resource "google_compute_network" "container_network" {
  name = "container-network"
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "sql" {
  name = "sql-private-ip"
  purpose = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network = google_compute_network.container_network.self_link
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "sql" {
  network = google_compute_network.container_network.self_link
  service = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.sql.name]
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "master" {
  provider = google-beta
  count = 1
  database_version = "MYSQL_5_7"

  depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.sql]

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled = false
      private_network = google_compute_network.container_network.id
    }
  }
}
```

When I use this config for a single database, this works fine. If I then change `count = 2`, that works fine as well. However, if I destroy the infrastructure and set `count = 2`, it fails.

```
Error: Error waiting for Create Instance: Failed to create subnetwork. <eye3 title='INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: New subnetwork overlaps with an IP range (10.28.0.0/24) in one of the active peers of an active peer (consumer-311061328248).
```

To me, this seems that the two databases are being created simultaneously and try to assign the same IP range.

Is there a way to create the databases sequentially instead or simultaneously? I suspect this will be a Terraform issue, rather than a GCP one although I'm open to ideas on this.

Comment: One option would be to have two `resource "google_sql_database_instance"` and set a `depends_on`on the second to the first, ... maybe a conditional depends_on based on the count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was testing to see if something fancy like depends on to self:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "master" {
  provider = google-beta
  count = 2
  database_version = "MYSQL_5_7"

  depends_on = [google_sql_database_instance.master[count.index-1]]

  ...
}
```

But nope, unfortunately not allowed, we get: `Error: Invalid expression`

> A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and
>   indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template
>   expressions, etc are allowed here.

Besides what I mentioned in the comments of using multiple `resource "google_sql_database_instance"` with dependencies between them *(not a big fan of that option)*...
the only other option I see is setting the terraform parallelism to 1 that will limit resource creation.
You can read more about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#parallelism-n

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who's first thought was a `depends_on`, especially as that's what one needs to do for the `google_service_network_connection` anyway.

I'll try the parallelism. It'll be slower, but I can enable that as necessary if it works. Thanks

Comment: Seems I'm not the only person who's asked after this feature https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14258

Comment: Ohh yeah, that `parallelism` per resource would be a nice addition

Comment: Yes, I agree there. Shame it's unlikely to happen. As a side note, I tried the exact same configuration on Pulumi and it worked without any problems. Seeing as I'm 50/50 whether to use Pulumi or Terraform, this might push me away from Terraform